# Как можно оптимизировать динамическое обновление контента что бы иметь возможность выделять и копировать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток, есть одна проблема в данной ситуации, а именно все что в блоке  **id=content**  скидывается выделение и ничего скопировать нельзя.

---

Как можно оптимизировать динамическое обновление контента что бы иметь возможность выделять и копировать?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var inProcess = false;
    function show_message() {
        if (inProcess) return;
            inProcess = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "table.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    inProcess = false;
                    $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            show_message();
            setInterval(function() {
                show_message();
            }, 1000);
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При замене HTML выделение с измененного фрагмента будет убрано браузером автоматически и нет способа этому помешать. Поэтому, что бы дать пользователям возможность нормально работать с выделением вы можете:

1. Увеличить интервал обновления контента.
2. Обновлять контент, только если от действительно изменился.
3. Обновлять не весь блок, а только его часть. Это особенно актуально, если только небольшая часть контента регулярно меняется (например таймер или часы).

**UPD:**

Приведу пример реализации ванта #2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var inProcess = false;
    var lastHTML = '';

    function show_message() {
        if (inProcess) return;
            inProcess = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "table.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    inProcess = false;
                    if (lastHTML !== html) {
                        $("#content").html(html);
                        lastHTML = html;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            show_message();
            setInterval(function() {
                show_message();
            }, 1000);
        });

</script>
```

Стоит отметить, что **правильнее** было бы получать с сервера дату последнего изменения контента и уже по ней определять нужно ли запрашивать (и обновлять) HTML разметку. Но тут все зависит от того, что за данные генерирует `table.php` и ведется ли учет их изменений.

Comment: пытался сделать по второму варианту, по нажатию кнопки, но тогда контент появляется когда нажимаешь кнопку, а до этого просто пустота    $(function() {
       $("#send").click(function(){ 
            show();  
          
        });  
        });

Comment: обновил ответ, добавив пример реализации пункта 2.

Comment: вот теперь работает, только lastHTML должно быть одного регистра

Comment: да, действительно, подправил

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще предотвращать обновление контента при наведении на него мышкой, и возвращать обновление при уводе курсора с блока.

Например создадим переменную `var preventUpdate = false;`
Потом примерно таким кодом будем её менять:

```
$("#content").on("mouseenter", function () {
    preventUpdate = true;
});
$("#content").on("mouseleave", function () {
    preventUpdate = false;
});
```

Далее в вашей функции show_message напишем простую проверку:

```
function show_message() {
    if (preventUpdate) {
        return;
    }

    // ajax...
}
```

Всё, пока идет взаимодействие с блоком, никаких его модификаций не будет.